# Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was () -> handle when importing tensor flow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

When i try to import tensorflow using the import command on python I get the error :

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py", line 38, in <module>
    _np_bfloat16 = pywrap_bfloat16.bfloat16_type()

TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
    () -> handle
```

Prior to this I had another error because of my numpy, but I installed the correct numpy version and no longer have a miss match between the module the api was compiled against and the one I have but I got this error instead and can't find the solution, help please :C